# To sort jsp parameters on page by entity id, Spring MVC, JQuery, JSP

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

The employees passed from model are not granted in order as the implementing type is **HashSet**.
Don't want to change at backend code, need to change on page only.
What is the best way to sort them in ascending order by age.

```
<td>
    <c:forEach items="${params.employees}" var="emp">
      ${emp.name} <i>${emp.age}</i><br />
    </c:forEach>
  </td>
```

Comment: If you have to have a HashMap, why not just send a sorted list of keys along with it?  On the Java side you are not causing that much overhead, as the List would contain the exact same objects as the Map's keys.  Then you can just `c:forEach` over the list, using it to get the item you need from the Map.

Comment: In back-end Employee are stored as 'HashSet', I don't want to replace it with 'TreeSet' or other sortable collection. And another point is at **Spring Controller** level, params refers 'Entity' directly. If the param is kind of DTO, I am sure I can use one of sortable collection.

Comment: You could use scriptlet, but I personally thing that scriptlet is the devil.  Or return your map in a wrapper that has sorting capabilities.  Or, switch to a sorted map.  I don't personally know of any way to sort directly in a JSP outside doing scriptlet to call the `java.util.Collections` to do so.

Comment: Yes **CodeChimp** scriptlet is the devil so I dropped it. Now, I fixed the issue by compiling the employees as object in Javascript array first and then sort by age. And finally I render them as Javascript's innerHTML method. Thanks for your input.